# pyspark equivalent of pandas groupby('col1').col2.head()

Tags: group-by, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sample

I have a Spark Dataframe where for each set of rows with a given column value (col1), I want to grab a sample of the values in (col2). The number of rows for each possible value of col1 may vary widely, so i'm just looking for a set number, say 10, of each type.

There may be a better way to do this, but the natural approach seemed to be a df.groupby('col1')

in pandas, I could do df.groupby('col1').col2.head()

i understand that spark dataframes are not pandas dataframes, but this is a good analogy.

i suppose i could loop over all of col1 types as a filter, but that seems terribly icky.

any thoughts on how to do this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me create a sample Spark dataframe with two columns.

```
df = SparkSQLContext.createDataFrame([[1, 'r1'],
 [1, 'r2'],
 [1, 'r2'],
 [2, 'r1'],
 [3, 'r1'],
 [3, 'r2'],
 [4, 'r1'],
 [5, 'r1'],
 [5, 'r2'],
 [5, 'r1']], schema=['col1', 'col2'])
df.show()

+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1|  r1|
|   1|  r2|
|   1|  r2|
|   2|  r1|
|   3|  r1|
|   3|  r2|
|   4|  r1|
|   5|  r1|
|   5|  r2|
|   5|  r1|
+----+----+
```

After grouping by col1, we get GroupedData object (instead of Spark Dataframe). You can use aggregate functions like min, max, average. But getting a head() is little bit tricky. We need to convert GroupedData object back to Spark Dataframe. This can be done Using pyspark `collect_list()` aggregation function.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions
df1 = df.groupBy(['col1']).agg(functions.collect_list("col2")).show(n=3)
```

Output is:

```
+----+------------------+
|col1|collect_list(col2)|
+----+------------------+
|   5|      [r1, r2, r1]|
|   1|      [r1, r2, r2]|
|   3|          [r1, r2]|
+----+------------------+
only showing top 3 rows
```

Comment: perfect. thank you. i think asking a question on stackoverflow is the process my brain uses to answer stuff -- i was able to do it with a udf shortly after posting -- but this is cleaner. i hadn't known about the collect_list() function; obviously need to review the sql.functions more too.